# fullcalendar - select callback function - will not clear the event upon new selection

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api, fullcalendar

When I make a selction on the calendar and add an event, it sends the info to my PHP script and the event is placed in the database as expected. Great!

The problem is when I select another date and add the event (without refresh), it adds the event twice in the MYSQL database. Not Great!

This perpetually adds up with the increasing clicks until a refresh is made. Also the "extra" events added have no time placed in the DB except for "0000-00-00 00:00:00", so in turn it appear correct upon output. Am I just missing something simple? What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

select: function(start, end, allDay){

  $("popup").show();
  $(".title").focus();
  var start = Date.parse(start) / 1000;
  var end = Date.parse(end) / 1000;
  var allDay = allDay:

  $("submitForm").click(function(){

    var title = $(".title").val();
    var description = $("description").val();
    var team_id = <?php echo $id ?>;

    if(title != "" || title != " "){

      $.post("script.php", {...}, function(){
        $(".title").val("");
        $(".description").val("");
        start = "";
        end = "";
        title = "";
        description = "";
        team_id = "";
        allDay = "";
        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
      });

    }else{
       alert("You must enter a title");
    }

   $(".popup").hide();

  });
}

});
</script>
```

Obviously this is not the entire JS/Jquery but this is what matters. What am I missing? Thanks in advance. Your help is appreciated!

Comment: You have a syntax error: change select: by select= in the line #2

Comment: @MartinBorthiry here are the docs http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/usage/. This is an api callback function and it should not be "=". Again the function actually works, it is just not releasing the object for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had to add a random session id to fix the problem and then clear the id after the post was completed.

Answer (score 1):

- Here you attach the click event repeatedly when you select a date.

  ```
  select: function(start, end, allDay){
     $("submitForm").click(function(){});
  })
  ```

  So, if your `$("popup")` exist on `document.ready` just put this line of code, outside 
  of the definition of the plugin
- Here submit form is found and click event is attached, no matter if the element has display:none property:

  ```
          $(document).ready(function() {
                 $("submitForm").click(function(){});
                 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({    
                          select:select: function(start, end, allDay){})
                 })
          })
  ```
- if you add the `$("popup")` element, later dynamically in the jQuery script you have to bind the click event, but be careful to put that code somewhere where it will be executed only once.

Comment: Still not doin' it for me. It still won't let go of the previous selection. Any other ideas?

Comment: well if $("submitForm") is a clickable HTML element like input, type="button" or <a>, try  $("submitForm").click(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); }); before the rest of the code. If this is not the case, post some more code of the script + html parts

Answer (score 0):

I guess your click is getting attached on each success. Place your code click function outside your success callback.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't place that portion of code in there but I will edit my post. I currently already have it within document.ready.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following in your success function:

```
                    $('#save_button').unbind()
```

So that as per @mehul9595 you remove all the accumulated events bound to the click.

Help from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9688908/2468603